# Encrypting string based on X509 .cer in Python on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, certificate, x509

As the title says, I have the .cer file and I want to encrypt a string. I've tried quite a few libs out there, w/o success. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an experience with this, but did you try [Keyczar](http://keyczar.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/python/) package by bundling it and trying to use that for your purposes. It has an [Encrypter class](http://www.keyczar.org/pydocs/keyczar.keyczar.Encrypter-class.html) for what you are trying to. It has a dependency on PyCrypto, but that seems already [included](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html) in the GAE infrastructure.

Comment: I think I'm getting this encryption wrong. Keyczar seems to need some prerequisite files to exist. I only have the .cer

Comment: See if you can export the public and private key separately from your cert and look the documentation of keyczar to use the correct keys for your encryption requirements?

Comment: I already have the public and private keys separated. As for the docs, they show only how to generate they keys.